# MySQL One to Many to Many To Many Conversion

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table having one to many relationship.

```
tblAuthor
id
name

tblPublisher
id
name

tblBooks
title
author_id
publisher_id
```

I am converting it to hold multiple Authors and Multiple Publisher. So my new table schema is now.

```
tblAuthor
id
name

tblPublisher
id
name

tblBooks
id
title

tblBooksAuthor
book_id
author_id

tblBooksPublisher
book_id
publihser_id
```

How can i migrate my data to new tables. And what is the best solution.`tblBooks` contain around 1M rows. Is insert into only way ?

```
INSERT INTO tblBooksPublisher (book_id, publihser_id)
SELECT id, publihser_id
FROM tblBooks;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you migrating data from SQL to SQL or a different source? If you are just creating separate tables into SQL then yes, the easiest way would be to insert data regardless the amount of data you have.